# Avoiding banned substances

Tags: strength-training, supplements

I'm looking around for some good supplements and have been recommended Matrix Anabolic Gold, but I'm keen to check there's no banned substances in it. `informed-sport.com` is good for checking a manufacturer is safe, but does anyone know if because it isn't registered, it's because it contains banned substances? Or if it's simply not been considered? The word anabolic in the title is just a marketing ploy I presume, which I'm not enticed or put off by, but the reviews are very good.

I'm anticipating a few people saying buy organic, but I'm not convinced that something being "natural" is better, so I'm open to all suggestions. If this Matrix stuff is not safe because of doping or contamination, my default is myprotein.com. Thanks

Comment: This is off topic, unless you can relate it to your own workout regiment. However, I encourage you to do so since I think this is a valuable information question. If you add what your current workouts are and why you want to use the supplement, that would bring it squarely on topic.

Comment: Just to add before this (probably) gets closed, if you check the FDA supplement recall list you'll see a lot of products yanked because of "unlisted drugs" found during testing that are not on the label. The best you can do is look for historically trusted companies, and anything that submits to true independent third party chemical testing.

Answer (score 2):

The Informed Sport website describes it's [registration process](http://informed-sport.com/en/product-registration-process), which can explain why a number of products are not registered.  Essentially, the manufacturer has to actively seek them out.  The major issue with the supplement market is that it is unregulated, and any voluntary regulation like this costs money.  Unless the companies who are registered get a noticeably larger market share of supplement sales, it's unlikely that a number of companies will self-register.

Looking at the ingredients listed on the [Matrix Anabolic Gold](http://www.matrix-nutrition.co.uk/buy.cfm/protein-powders/matrix-anabolic-gold-5kg/79/yes/84328) website, we see the followoing:

> Matrix Protein Blend – (Whey Protein Concentrate (Milk), Whey Protein Isolate (Milk), Soya Protein Isolate, Milk Protein Concentrate, Whole Milk Protein). Flavouring. Amino Acid Matrix – (Leucine, Iso-Leucine, Valine, Lysine, Arginine, Creatine Monohydrate, Glycine, Taurine, Peptide Bonded Glutamine (derived from Wheat Protein). Natural Colourings, Acacia Gum, Stabilisers (Citric Acid, Malic Acid), Sweetener: Sucralose.

You can look up the ingredients on [Examine.com](http://examine.com/) (a web site that reviews scientific studies in relation to supplements and summarizes them in one place), but I can summarize what most of the ingredients are:

- **Whey Protein Concentrate and Isolate** -- It's just whey protein.  The isolate is a bit more refined to just protein than concentrate.
- **Soya Protein Isolate** -- It's very refined soy protein.  While soy is a phyto-estrogen, it shouldn't pose any problems being this refined.
- **Milk Protein Concentrate** -- Most likely a combination of whey and casein from a very cheap refining process.
- **Leucine, Iso-Leucine, Valine, Lysine, Arginine** -- Branched Chain Amino Acids, the body can use these best after exertion.  It's just standard stuff, check Examine.com for what each does and how well it does it's job.
- **Creatine Monohydrate** -- A compound that helps your body turn ADP back into usable ATP (energy used in muscle).  It works well, is safe, legal, and pretty inexpensive if you buy it separately.
- **Glycine, Taurine, and Peptide Bonded Glutamine** -- More amino acids.  Nothing to be alarmed about.
- **Everything Else** -- Just fillers to make it taste OK.

The mix is pretty standard stuff, nothing that would be considered banned by sports associations or by national laws.  Assuming those are 100% of the active ingredients, you won't experience any more enhanced performance than you would with any other equivalent supplement.

I will call attention to the protein blends.  Isolates give you more protein per volume than concentrates, but are expensive to produce.  Concentrates work well, but the processing isn't as refined.  If there's any traces of bad things like arsenic, etc. from that old Consumer Reports scare article it would be more likely to be in the concentrate.  The plain milk protein concentrate is probably a bit less processed and probably lower quality.

Answer (score 0):

There are two other places that you can go to check supplements and medications against what is and is not banned.

The [Global Drug Reference Online](http://www.globaldro.com/us-en/) (Global DRO) gives guidance on pharmaceutical products, such as if they are banned either in our out of competition (IC and OOC respectively), and other information pertinent. For example, some medications are legal if you take them orally, but illegal if you get an injection.

The other site is the [Supplement 411](http://www.supplement411.org/hrl/) put out by the United States Anti Doping Agency (USADA). This is the organization that works with the US National Governing Bodies (NGB's) to ensure clean athletes in the Olympic umbrella (Pan Olympic, Para Olympic, etc.). You don't necessarily have to register with complete information, however I encourage you to do so as they update the list regularly.

Currently, I do not find Matrix Anabolic Gold on the list. That is not 100%, as they may not have tested it yet, but every time I've looked for a known illegal supplement that it is already on the list.